# $\lbrace{ r(x)f(x) + s(x)g(x) : r(x),s(x)\in F[x] }\rbrace$ is a proper ideal on $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Let $F$ a field and $f,g\in R[x]$. Suppose that the set

$\lbrace{ r(x)f(x) + s(x)g(x) : r(x),s(x)\in F[x] }\rbrace$

is a proper ideal on $F[x]$

It shows that if the degrees of $f$ and $g$ are different, then $f$ and $g$ are not both irreducible.

Answer (score 2):

If $\deg f\neq \deg g$ (and $g\neq 0$) and $f$ and $g$ are both irreducible, it follows that $f$ and $g$ are coprime, so by Bezout's lemma, there exists $a(x),b(x)\in F[x]$ such that $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)=1$, and thus the ideal generated by $f$ and $g$ is in fact the entire ring $F[x]$. Thus, the ideal is not proper.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f,g$ are irreducible in $F[x]$.

Then, since $f,g$ have distinct degrees, neither is a constant times the other.

It follows that $f,g$ have no common factor in $F[x]$, hence by the Euclidean algorithm, there exist $a,b$ in $F[x]$ such that $af + bg = 1$.

But then the ideal $(f,g)=(1)$, which is not a proper ideal.